# Cyassl-2.4.2 missing libcyassl.a file

Tags: c++, c, unix, ssl, wolfssl

I'm have built and installed Cyassl-2.4.2 on my unix machine to use with a project of mine; however, when I try to compile my c project, the compiler cannot find the libcyassl.a file. I have searched many times in the Cyassl.2.4.2 folder and am unable to find the file myself. Where is this file locate? Have I missed a step in bulding/installing Cyassl.2.4.2? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I had successfully built and installed CyaSSL 2.4.2 here and this is what I got:**

**~/cyassl$ find . -iname "*.a"**

./src/.libs/libcyassl.a

**~/cyassl$ ls /usr/local/lib/**

libcyassl.a  libcyassl.la  libcyassl.so  libcyassl.so.3  libcyassl.so.3.0.3

---

**The building process used was:**

./autogen.sh

./configure

make

sudo make install

**The installation prints out:**

> ---
>
> Libraries have been installed in:
>      /usr/local/lib
>
> If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
>   in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
>   specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
>   flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
>      - add LIBDIR to the`LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
>        during execution
>      - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
>        during linking
>      - use the`-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
>      - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'
>
> See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
>   more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
>
> ---

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It turns out I was not doing the appropriate autoconf and automake sequence of commands when compiling.